# Apple Developer Program "Closed?"

Tags: developer-program

So to try and give a quick backstory, I've been learning Swift in hopes of reaching the goal of a released piece of iOS software. Now I know that you need to be a part of the developer program to do this, so I looked into it today.

What I read and clicked through so I could get to the last step possible without actually paying, and I got to a page that said "You cannot enroll in the developer program right now."

Is this a problem, or is Apple just fixing it right now?

And here's a screenshot of the page, if it helps:

[image].

Answer (score 3):

it is possible they are updating or doing something with there servers as they say at this time .. try later

Answer (score 2):

I tried to replicate your problem and it seems to be working now. I was able to get to the purchase confirmation page with no problem.